# HOW TO POST DATA IN NODE.JS

Tags: node.js, json, api, npm

So basically after looking at the api documentation for c0gnito.cc I tried setting up
calling the api and trying to post data, I hope what I did makes enough sense but how would
I post this data in Node.js?

```json
"url": "api.c0gnito.cc/generate-keys",
"headers": {
 "privateKey": "privatekey",
 "numberOfLicenses": "1",
 "expiryTime": "24",
 "customMask": "HITLIST-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx"
}
```

EDIT: I do not understand how I can POST this data, i would appreciate an example, an example to post data as shown above.

Comment: Please post your actual code for making the request, not just the arguments.  Also, the `request()` module is now deprecated and not recommended for new projects.  You can see a list of alternatives [here](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3143).  My favorite is [`got()`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got).

Comment: @jfriend00 thanks for letting me know but ive edited the description to explain what i was trying to ask better, im trying to ask for an example of how it would be possible to post such data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [`got()` library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got#api) (instead of the deprecated request library) and using the headers you show, you could do something like this:

```
const got = require('got');

got.post("http://api.c0gnito.cc/generate-keys", {
    headers: {
        privateKey: "privatekey",
        numberOfLicenses: "1",
        expiryTime: "24",
        customMask: "HITLIST-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx"
    }
}).then(results => {
    console.log(results);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```